# Vagrant Puppet using wget to fetch and extract .zip file

Tags: linux, vagrant, puppet

Hi I am creating a Vagrant setup and I am needing to fetch a .zip file which will be put in /vagrant/www directory.

They way I am trying to do this is:

```
 exec { 'setup octobercms':
    command => "/bin/sh -c 'wget -P /vagrant/www https://github.com/octobercms/install/archive/master.zip'",
    timeout => 900,
    logoutput => true
}
```

When vagrant up has been triggered I can see that the file is downloading but it is not appearing in the /vagrant/www directory. The file is not really anything to do with vagrant but will be used to install October CMS.

When using puppet what would be the best way to fetch a zipped file and extract its contents into a directory and remove the zipped archive?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` command is run in a generic construct of the shell, and doesn't obey the constraints of the user account evoking it. Try:

```
exec { 'setup octobercms':
    command => "cd /vagrant/www/; /bin/sh -c 'wget https://github.com/octobercms/install/archive/master.zip'",
    timeout => 900,
    logoutput => true
}
```

Comment: You may also need to remove the /bin/sh -c, and use the absolute path to wget such as /usr/bin/wget 'https://github.com/octobercms/install/archive/master.zip'

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested and the following error happened: `err: /Stage[main]/Octobercms/Exec[setup octobercms]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command 'cd'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you'll need to use VAGRANT_CWD to change the working directory. See http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/environmental-variables.html

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin and won't work just like that. You can try adding `provider => 'shell'` to your `exec`. Launching `sh` explicitly should then not be necessary anymore. Personally, I would do none of that and use `wget -O /vagrant/www/master.zip` instead.